# jenkins job to check if port 80 responds to a http request

Tags: jenkins

I am new to jenkins.I need to create a jenkins job to check if port 80 responds to a http request with 200 and restart apache if it is not.Please advise.

Comment: What is the problem exactly?

Comment: Do u have any idea in configuring the job

Comment: @SarathSasi that's kind of the question back at you "Do ***u*** have any idea in configuring the job". If you don't know anything about Jenkins, unfortunately this website is not a guide to give you that knowledge. You've got to learn Jenkins first, and then if you are stuck on particular issue, then you can ask for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need **[Conditional Build Step](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin)** and **[HTTP Request](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/HTTP+Request+Plugin)** plugins.
Enable build step as condition in global configuration.
Setup a job with Conditional build step executing HTTP Request plugin, and on failure restart apache.

Restarting apache can be done through [**Publish over SSH**](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+SSH+Plugin) plugin, or through **Execute shell** buildstep, if you are on Linux. If you are on Windows, you will need **Execute batch command** buildstep, and then use `plink.exe` that comes with `Putty` to connect to your apache server. This is all providing that your apache server is running on Linux in the first place.

If your apache is on Windows, that's a whole different can of worms.

You are not providing any information in your question, and as it is, it is too broad and shows zero research on your part.